# MK 1 citi sport temp gauge fault

Tags: cooling-system, cooling

I own a MK 1 Citi Golf Sport 1.6 Carb that has 523220 km. I recently flushed the cooling system and changed the coolant. After the flush the temperature showed above normal despite changing everything. I also replaced the thyristor and still the temperature gauge reads above normal 50%. The fan kicks in as normal and the car is not overheating.

I have had a dry and wet pressure test done, compression good. There is no mixing of water and oil. I have changed the water pump, checked fuses, checked the instrument cluster and electrics, and all circuitry is good.

I have done this so many times before and never had problems until now. What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the wiring to that little brass looking temperature sender on the coolant elbow where all the radiator pipes meet.  Make sure the connection is good and there is no corrosion on the terminals.

The cause could also be related to a bad or corroded earth behind the clocks in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is to have a scan performed on the vehicle. The probable faults to me from your question is that you may have changed parts, thyristor, that is not exactly the right one. They can come colour coded for differant temperature ranges. Other then that, because of the vehicles age a resistance is present in the temp gauge circuit. This may be in the wiring or the gauge assembly itself.

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks. yep, car is still in perfect condition until this temp gauge issue. connected aux temp gauge today, fan is coming in at 87.5- 88 deg. as before. thyristor and other parts are correct for golf range. Will have resistance circuitry checked tomorrow. she`s a 1988 model that was manufactured here in South Africa.